# adding text to legend from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, legend

how can i add text to a legend from code behind

Comment: Can you add more details? What is a legend? Do you mean the `<legend>` tag? "code behind" indicates that you are using APS.NET?

Comment: Could you give more context? What do you mean by "a legend" here? Assuming this is in a UI of some kind, is it WinForms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET, ASP.NET MVC, something else? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: sorry for that, ya iam talking about <legend> ag of html i am using it inside an list view and i want to know how to assign its value from code behind. Actually i am not getting how to find a legend control using listview.findcontrol

Comment: Is it on each item in the listview or is it in the layout?

Comment: yes it is in each item in the list view i have added it in listviews item template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about the [HTML Legend Tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_legend.asp) and using C# in an ASP.NET site. You can give it an ID and a runat="server" then you can access it from the code behind by name and change its text property.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<fieldset>
<legend id="myLegend" runat="server">Personalia:</legend>
Name: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
Email: <input type="text" size="30" /><br />
Date of birth: <input type="text" size="10" />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Then in the code behind:

```
myLegend.InnerText = "Foo";
```