# How to access a legend tag from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms, repeater

I have the following data-bound `repeater` code :

```
<%--categories--%>
<asp:Repeater ID="CategoryRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="groupbox">
            <fieldset>
                <legend><%# Container.DataItem %></legend>
                <table>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="ItemRepeater" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:CheckBox id="chkItem" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text")%>' />
                            <asp:HiddenField id="pgNos" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("PGNos")%>' />
                            <asp:Button ID="btnXRefs" Text="x-refs" runat="server" CssClass="xRefButton" OnClick="btnSelectXRefs_Click" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </table>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

There is a `repeater` inside a `repeater`. How do I access the text inside the `legend` (`<legend><%# Container.DataItem %></legend>`) from code?

I tried :

```
foreach (RepeaterItem cr in CategoryRepeater.Items)
{
string heading = (string) cr.DataItem; // returns null
}
```

Comment: This is something similar  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770143/adding-text-to-legend-from-code-behind

Comment: Alternatively you can use Headertemplate http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.headertemplate.aspx

Comment: Where do you want to access it from? Example, btnSelectXRefs_Click or ItemBound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legend tag that you use is not visible on server side. Is a client control and not a server one.

Try with this:

```
<legend id="myLegend" runat="server"><%# Container.DataItem %></legend>
```

Then in codebehind:

```
protected void ItemBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.DataItem == null) return;
        HtmlGenerics body = (HtmlGenerics)e.Item.FindControl("myLegend");
        body.InnerText = "Foo";
    }
```

Comment: I did -- var fileName = ((HtmlGenericControl) cr.FindControl("heading")).InnerText;

Answer (score 2):

**Container.DataItem** is a runtime alias for the DataItem for this specific item in the bound list.  For a **Repeater** which displays 10 rows of data, this is one row from the datasource...Basically, it's a specific row and at runtime you can get the Property Values from this row

I saw your above **Mark Up**...Seems like you are missing to mention the property of Data-Bound type Class like below.

```
<%# ((Your Class Name)Container.DataItem).Class Property Name %>
```

---

> There is a repeater inside a repeater. How do I access the text inside
>   the legend (<%# Container.DataItem %>) from code?

As told by **phemt.latd**, you can change the **Legend tag** into server side control like below.

```
<legend id="lg" runat="server">
      <%# ((Your Class Name)Container.DataItem).Class Property Name %>
</legend>
```

Now, in the **Item-Bound** Data Event, Find the Legend Control.

```
protected void rpt_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
                           e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        HtmlGenericControl ctl = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("lg");
        ctl.InnerText //This is what will give you the result.
    }
}
```